# How does a rescan LUN on Linux works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, storage, scsi

We can issue a host bus scan on Linux host to get the /dev/sd* devices on host.

The scan is issued using this command :
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan

Can someone please tell me the flow of events in the Linux userspace/kernel code which leads to formation of /dev/sd* devices post scsi scan ?

Is this a PCI bus scan OR SCSI commands sent to controller of storage OR something new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked upon the code how iscsid scan works. **__scsi_scan_target** is the key function which does the SCSI scan.
This function first it tries to probe and add LUN 0 using **scsi_probe_and_add_lun** function.

```
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e8c94>] scsi_probe_and_add_lun+0x3f4/0xc80
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815e5a51>] ? printk+0x77/0x8e
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e9a0e>] __scsi_scan_target+0x13e/0x270
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e9c30>] scsi_scan_target+0xf0/0x110
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050eedf>] iscsi_user_scan_session.part.13+0x10f/0x150 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050ef20>] ? iscsi_user_scan_session.part.13+0x150/0x150 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050ef41>] iscsi_user_scan_session+0x21/0x30 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b1b63>] device_for_each_child+0x53/0x90
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050cb6c>] iscsi_user_scan+0x3c/0x60 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813eb835>] store_scan+0xa5/0x100
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b1138>] dev_attr_store+0x18/0x30
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81225686>] sysfs_write_file+0xc6/0x140
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff811afa7d>] vfs_write+0xbd/0x1e0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff811b04c8>] SyS_write+0x58/0xb0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815fc9d9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

scsi_probe_and_add_lun function will : 
1. allocate scsi_device data structure
2. call **scsi_probe_lun** and send SCSI enquiries to LUN 0.
3. call **scsi_add_lun** to fill the scsi_device data structure from the enquiries done. 
    this data structure is added using **scsi_sysfs_add_sdev** function.

Then it tries to send **SCSI report LUN command** to get the number of LUNS in function **scsi_report_lun_scan**. This function finds the number of LUNs and again tries to add all the LUNs using scsi_probe_and_add_lun function.

**scsi_sysfs_add_sdev** function adds the devices by calling scsi_target_add and device_add for scsi_device.

This device_add calls the drivers' probe function **(sd_probe)**:

```
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa01d77d0>] sd_probe+0x320/0x380 [sd_mod]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b6917>] driver_probe_device+0x87/0x390
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b6c20>] ? driver_probe_device+0x390/0x390
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b6c5b>] __device_attach+0x3b/0x40
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b477b>] bus_for_each_drv+0x6b/0xb0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b6818>] device_attach+0x88/0xa0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b5b18>] bus_probe_device+0x98/0xc0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b3584>] device_add+0x4c4/0x7a0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813c2ebc>] ? __pm_runtime_resume+0x5c/0x80
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813eba9c>] scsi_sysfs_add_sdev+0xac/0x320
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e9317>] scsi_probe_and_add_lun+0xa77/0xc80
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815eceff>] scsi_report_lun_scan+0x39a/0x5f1
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e9a24>] __scsi_scan_target+0x154/0x270
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813e9c30>] scsi_scan_target+0xf0/0x110
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050eedf>] iscsi_user_scan_session.part.13+0x10f/0x150 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050ef20>] ? iscsi_user_scan_session.part.13+0x150/0x150 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050ef41>] iscsi_user_scan_session+0x21/0x30 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b1b63>] device_for_each_child+0x53/0x90
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffffa050cb6c>] iscsi_user_scan+0x3c/0x60 [scsi_transport_iscsi]
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813eb835>] store_scan+0xa5/0x100
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff813b1138>] dev_attr_store+0x18/0x30
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff81225686>] sysfs_write_file+0xc6/0x140
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff811afa7d>] vfs_write+0xbd/0x1e0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff811b04c8>] SyS_write+0x58/0xb0
Dec 24 03:24:28 localhost kernel: [<ffffffff815fc9d9>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

linux-3.14.69\drivers\scsi\sd.c

This sd_probe function allocates the disk and launches thread **sd_probe_async**.

```
async_schedule_domain(sd_probe_async, sdkp, &scsi_sd_probe_domain);
```

**sd_probe_async** calls **add_disk** and prints the message :
"Attached SCSI %sdisk"

Comment: Put the same info here : http://sklinuxblog.blogspot.com/2017/01/scsi-user-scan-scsi-device-addition.html